# Can Veracode detect vulnerabilities in jsp files?

Tags: java, client-side

We have chosen Veracode to perform security assessment of our JavaEE code. We have been performing white-box security testing using Veracode. As I am quite new to Veracode, I was surprised to find no results for our imperfect jsp files. All the results were around a few servelets. Also we did not find any results in our Manager classes and Service Classes (backend code). Please guide. What am I missing here?

Comment: There in an answer from Veracode or the question.https://getsatisfaction.com/veracode/topics/veracode_support_for_jsp_files

Answer (score 2):

Hi and thanks for your feedback. I can offer you some general information here and provide suggestions about how we can dig into your specific application.

First, Veracode does have support for JSPs. We generally precompile the JSPs upon your submission so that we can ensure we have all the necessary supporting pieces, then we analyze the resulting bytecode alongside the rest of your compiled Java code.

There are a few things that can go wrong when a customer uploads JSPs:

1. *JSPs cannot be compiled*. This happens when either a supporting
   library required by the JSP is not present in the upload, or the JSP
   is in an uncompilable state. We report back any JSP compilation
   failures in the prescan report, so if you see these it's generally a
   sign that we won't be able to analyze the content of the JSPs. If
   you see these warnings, check to see if you are missing a class
   dependency and see if you can upload it so we can get a good
   compiled version of your JSP.
2. *There's a packaging issue*. While we can handle a few different ways to package your application, the Veracode service gets best
   results if you upload a web application as a properly packaged WAR
   file, including the web.xml. If you upload the application packaged
   in a different way we may not be able to put the JSPs in their
   proper context for analysis. This is an area we're working on,
   because we realize that not every Java application server requires
   WARs, and you may be deploying using a different model.
3. *We don't support one of your frameworks*. Because Veracode does a full data- and control-flow analysis of the application, we need to
   have an understanding of everything that might impact the control
   flow, including frameworks. We typically try to call out unsupported
   frameworks at upload time as well; obviously that's not something
   you'll be able to address with a quick fix, but we try to be as
   transparent as we can about what we can analyze and what we can't.

All of that aside, we may simply have an issue in our engine when it comes to your application. The best thing to do is to schedule a readout with our service team so we can look at your results with you and offer you advice for your specific application. Depending on your subscription, you may have a "Request a Readout" button directly in the UI; if you don't, please contact us at support at veracode.com and we'll see what we can do to answer your concerns.